# Why finding element in undefined context return value?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div id='div1'>
<input type='text' value='sdcsdc'>
</div>
<div id='div2'>

</div>
<div id='div3'>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#div3').text($('input', undefined).val());
```

I am finding `input` in undefined context, so if context is not even defined, how something can be found in it?

It is returning me value of only input on document.

Please don't answer like 'May be it is .....'.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't has any content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because jQuery defaults to the `document` when you provide a falsy value for the context.

Here is the [source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=init).

Comment: Do you have any resource for it? According your answer, `document` is default but when you used `undefined` jquery should replace `document` to `undefined`. And in this case code shulden't has any result.

Comment: Yep, it's right in the source: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=init. As I said, jQuery will ignore any value you provide as a context which will coerce to `false` (ie. `null`, `''`, `0`, `undefined`) and replace it with the `document`.